# explanation of c++ class instances behavor

Tags: c++, windows

I Can't properly understand what is exactly happening when class instances are creating and when an instances methods are invoking.

For example there's a folowing c++ code:

```
class A {
     int a;  
     void print_my_a();

  public:
     A();
};

void A:: print_my_a() {
  cout << a << '\n';  
}

A::A(): a(10) {}


int main() { 

  A Aobj1 = A();
  A Aobj2 = A();

  Aobj1.print_my_a();
  Aobj2.print_my_a();

  return 0;

}
```

so the question is:
Do each `Aobj1` and `Aobj2` instance refer to only one `print_my_a()` method ? or they both have their own `print_my_a()`?

Comment: First of all, this won't compile. Secondly methods are shared among all instances of a class (they're just code), what isn't shared is member variables, in this case `int a`. Each instance of `A` can have separate values for `int a`, but your code doesn't demonstrate this as your constructor sets the value to `10`

Answer (score 1):

All functions are code, and all code in C++ is shared. However, it does not really make any difference, because the code cannot be modified anyway.

However, the local variables created during the runtime of each method, instance or static, are per invocation, so if you call the same method twice, concurrently or not, each method would have its own local variables.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is only an abstraction over the layout of data and code in the executable. Functions have one copy in the code segment and are shared between objects.

Comment: yeah but what changes exactly makes that abstraction to the code ? in other words what is the global difference between these two function invocations: obj.method(); and just method(); ??

Comment: `obj.method()` calls the member function `method` of the class of `obj`; just `method()` (in `main()`) calls the free function `method()`. Those are two different functions .

Answer (score 0):

The code for the method exists only once, but "this"-pointer "passed" to the method will be different.

If you rewrite print_my_a as follows, it gets much clearer:

```
void A::print_my_a() {
    cout << this->a << '\n';  
}
```

Hence: 
Aobj1.print_my_a() will have this pointer pointing to Aobj1
and Aobj2.print_my_a() will have this pointer pointing to Aobj2.

Answer (score 0):

An object owns it's own instance of data members. So a separate instance of `int a` is owned by both of your  objects `Aobj1` & `Aobj2`. The methods are not owned by the object, but they use the state of the object (the data member instances for the object) which has made the call.